# Cerrar <div> con cualquier botón

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo cerrar el div también con los botones que se encuentran dentro de él?

Logro hacerlo, pero solo con un botón y me interesa cerrarlo con cualquiera de los que están dentro:

```js
function openFunctions() {
    var div = document.getElementById("functions");
    div.classList.toggle("block");
}
```

```css
#functions{
margin-top: 20px;
background-color: #eee;
display: none;
}
#functions button{
display: block;
}
.block{
display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="openFunctions()">Abrir y cerrar</button>

<div id="functions">
<button>Funcion 1</button>
<button>Funcion 2</button>
<button>Funcion 3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo que deseas agregando al evento clic de todos los botones una llamada a tu función de la siguiente manera:

```js
/* Tu función */
function openFunctions() {
    var div = document.getElementById("functions");
    div.classList.toggle("block");
}
/* Esperamos a que el DOM esté cargado */
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  /* Agregamos tu función al evento clic de todos los botones */
  document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((boton) => {
    boton.addEventListener('click', openFunctions);
  });
});
```

```css
#functions {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #eee;
  display: none;
}
#functions button {
  display: block;
}
.block {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<button>Abrir y cerrar</button>

<div id="functions">
<button>Funcion 1</button>
<button>Funcion 2</button>
<button>Funcion 3</button>
</div>
```

He hecho uso de [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) para buscar todos los botones a los que deseamos agregar la función. Si quieres agregarla únicamente a los botones que están bajo `#functions` entonces el selector sería, por ejemplo, `#functions button`.

Con [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) itero uno a uno los resultados de la búsqueda realizada.

El método [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) agrega una llamada a la función especificada cuando se genere el evento del primer parámetro.

En el caso de los botones el evento `click` es el primer parámetro y el segundo es el nombre de la función que hemos creado anteriormente.

En el caso de `document` espero al evento `DOMContentLoaded` y en este caso, en vez de proporcionar el nombre de una función como segundo parámetro, la genero en línea usando el formato de [función reducida](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions#Funciones_reducidas) indicando `(parámetros) => {contenido de la función}`.